# How do I get the inverse of this equation?

Tags: inverse, inverse-function

The equation is the following:
$$y = \frac{x}{x-2}$$

What I did is:

$$y = \frac{x}{x-2}$$

$$y \times (x-2) = x$$

$$\frac{x-2}{x} = \frac{1}{y}$$

$$\frac{x}{x}-\frac{2}{x} = \frac{1}{y}$$

$$1-\frac{2}{x} = \frac{1}{y}$$

$$1-\frac{x}{2} = y$$

I've got a lot of doubts about that last step. Besides that, the result according to the textbook is the following:

$$ f^{−1}(x)=-\frac{2x}{x−1} $$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The reciprocal of $1-\frac2x$ is not $1-\frac x2$

Comment: Thanks @J.W.Tanner! What is it then? Any resource you can recommend?

Comment: If $\,\dfrac1y=1-\dfrac2x,$ then $y=\dfrac1{1-\dfrac2x}=\dfrac x{x-2}$

Comment: Isn't the result $\color{red}+\dfrac {2x}{x-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, no, you can't take recirocals of the terms the way you have.

That is

$\frac {1}{a+b} \ne \frac 1a + \frac 1b$

Anyway

$y = \frac{x}{x-2}\\
y(x-2) = x\\
yx - 2y = x\\
yx - x = 2y\\
x(y-1) = 2y\\
x = \frac {2y}{y-1}$

$f^{-1}(y) = \frac {2y}{y-1}$

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Doug M!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $x\neq2$, we can multiply both sides by $x-2$, giving $xy-2y=x\to x(y-1)=2y$. If $y=1$, there is no $x$ that satisfies the equation. If $y\neq1$, then $$x=\frac{2y}{y-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to note that
$$
y = \frac{x}{x-2} = \frac{(x-2)+2}{x-2} = 1+\frac{2}{x-2}
$$
Hence, $(x-2)(y-1) = 2$ and $x = \frac{2}{y-1}+2 = \frac{2y}{y-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align} 
y &= \frac{x}{x-2}
.
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
y&=\frac{x+2-2}{x+2}
,\\
y&=1-\frac 2{x+2}
,\\
y-1&=-\frac 2{x+2}
,\\
-\frac{y-1}2&=\frac 1{x+2}
,\\
x+2 &=\frac 2{1-y}
,\\
x &=\frac 2{1-y}-2;
,\\
x &=\frac{2\,y}{1-y}
,
\end{align}

so the answer is indeed

\begin{align} 
f^{-1}(x)=\frac{2x}{1-x}
.
\end{align}